# Clang CFE Compilation unable to read file

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to compile test files using the Clang Compiler FrontEnd with the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <llvm/Support/Host.h>
#include <llvm/Support/Program.h>
#include <llvm/Support/FileSystem.h>
#include <llvm/Support/VirtualFileSystem.h>
#include "clang/Basic/LLVM.h"
// #include <clang/Driver/ToolChain.h>
#include <clang/Driver/Driver.h>
#include <clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h>
#include <clang/Basic/DiagnosticIDs.h>
#include <clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Driver/Compilation.h>

using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang;
std::string pwd = "/home/arch/Documents/CFE/Examples/Compile/";
std::string target_executable = pwd + "target";

int main()
{
  llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<DiagnosticsEngine> DE(clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(new DiagnosticOptions));
  llvm::ErrorOr<std::string> clangPath = llvm::sys::findProgramByName("clang++");
  Driver D(StringRef(clangPath.get().c_str()), llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple(), *DE, "clang LLVM compiler", InMemoryFileSystem);
  // D.setCheckInputsExist(false);
  std::vector<const char *> args;
  args.push_back(clangPath.get().c_str());
  args.push_back((target_executable + ".cpp").c_str());
  args.push_back("-cl-std=clc++2021");
  args.push_back(("-o " + target_executable + ".spv").c_str());
  ArrayRef<const char *> compileArgs(args);
  std::unique_ptr<Compilation> C(D.BuildCompilation(compileArgs));
  assert(C > 0);
  bool CallbackHasCalled = false;
  C->setPostCallback(
      [&](const Command &Cmd, int Ret)
      { std::cout << "postCallback return value: " << Ret << std::endl; 
      CallbackHasCalled = true; });

  const JobList &Jobs = C->getJobs();
  auto &CmdCompile = Jobs.getJobs().front();
  const Command *FailingCmd = nullptr;
  assert(C->ExecuteCommand(*CmdCompile, FailingCmd));
  assert(FailingCmd);
}
```

With the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project("CLANG_CFE")
find_package(Clang REQUIRED)
target_precompile_headers(clangBasic PUBLIC)
execute_process(COMMAND clang-config --libs OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_LIBRARIES)
execute_process(COMMAND clang-config --cxx-flags OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_CXX_FLAGS)
add_executable(compile_example main.cpp)
target_compile_options(compile_example PRIVATE ${LLVM_CXX_FLAGS})
set(CLANG_LIBS clangBasic clangDriver clangFrontend)
target_link_libraries(compile_example PRIVATE  ${CLANG_LIBS} LLVMSupport)
```

The code compiles fine but fails to read the `target_executable`, resulting in the following error:

```
error: no such file or directory: 'P�ZUU'
```

Is this a read/write permission-error?

Comment: Is the encoding mess of "P�ZUU" mangled by the terminal, the filesystem or by your compiler? That might indicate where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with the usage of absolute paths, the method `Driver::DiagnoseInputExistence` automatically rejects the file path if it starts with `"/"`.

Using a relative filepath solved this issue.